# replace single character with multiple characters at different positions

Tags: javascript, string, str-replace

I have a string in JS for example

```
var str = "hello @something and @someone ok";
```

I want to replace characters starting with @, which I'm doing by matching the pattern by regex, for example

```
str.replace(/@([^ ]+\s[^ ]+)/g, '<a href="'+link+'"> $& </a>')
```

Suppose the string is `var str = "hello @something";` so the replacement is working fine for this as it searches for @ and replaces it with the `<a href>` but if the string is `var str = "hello @something and @someone ok";` then first it replaces @something with correct href and then replaces @someone with correct href which eventually changes the href of @something to the href of @someone.
I want the hrefs of both the values to be different.

Comment: `var str = hello @something and @someone ok I` That is invalid syntax, strings need delimiters around them...

Comment: So, what sort of output exactly would you want from an input of `@something and @someone`? Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you please give an example of your input and what output you want?

Comment: I want @something should be replaced with `<a href="link of something"> something </a>`

Comment: Are you calling `str.replace` once or twice?

Comment: no calling it once @ThomasSablik

Comment: How do you pass the two different links to `str.replace`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are doing following:

You store a string containing multiple `@`

```
var str = "hello @something and @someone ok";
```

and a link

```
var link = "stackoverflow.com";
```

Then you apply `str.replace` on this string

```
str = str.replace(/@([^ ]+\s[^ ]+)/g, '<a href="'+link+'"> $& </a>');
```

The result is

```
"hello <a href="stackoverflow.com"> @something </a> and <a href="stackoverflow.com"> @someone </a> ok"
```

Next you change the link

```
link = "stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript";
```

and apply `str.replace` again on your string

```
str = str.replace(/@([^ ]+\s[^ ]+)/g, '<a href="'+link+'"> $& </a>');
```

The result is

```
"hello <a href="stackoverflow.com"> <a href="stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> @something </a> </a> and <a href="stackoverflow.com"> <a href="stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript"> @someone </a> </a> ok"
```

That's your problem. To fix it you should remove the `g` from your regex and remove the `@` in the replace. Then every string will be replaced only once with the correct link. Also you should change your regex. My recommendation is

```
var str = "hello @something and @someone ok";
var link = "stackoverflow.com";
str = str.replace(/@(\w+)/, '<a href="'+link+'"> $1 </a>');
link = "stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript";
str =  str.replace(/@(\w+)/, '<a href="'+link+'"> $1 </a>');
```